# VBA Code to insert row below specific text value

Tags: vba, excel

I need insert a row below the text value of "Grand Total". I need the code to loop through all active worksheets. It only needs to look through column A. I am new to VBA so the easier the code the better.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you need:

```
    Sub InsertLineAfterGrandTotal()
    Dim WS          As Integer
    Dim LastLine    As Long
    Dim LookingArea As Range
    Dim FoundCell   As Range
    For WS = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(WS).Activate
        On Error Resume Next ' To avoid error when all cells are empty
        LastLine = Sheets(WS).Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set LookingArea = Sheets(WS).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastLine, 1))
        Set FoundCell = LookingArea.Find("Grand Total", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Grand Total not found in sheet " & Sheets(WS).Name & _
                ". Press Ok to continue", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Not found"
        Else
            FoundCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Explaining:

1) The `For` looping make it goes throughout all worksheets in your workbook.

2) `LastLine`, as the name says, gets the last line of active worksheet.

3) `LookingArea` is the range where the string `Grand Total` will be searched for.

4) `FoundCell` will point to the cell where `Grand Total` is found. If it is not found, a message box will appear, if it is found a new line is inserted above it.

Comment: Your code returns Runtime Error 91 when all cells are empty within a sheet. To avoid that you can insert `On Error Resume Next` before clause starting with LastLine